# Why the gradient vector gives the direction of maximum increase of a function?

Tags: calculus, functions, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

Why the gradient vector gives the direction of maximum increase of a function? In context of multivariable functions, $$f: \Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R} $$

Y know that the gradient vector is defined as $$\nabla f(x,y) = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$$

And I understand that the partial derivatives gives the increase value in the directions of i and j versor respectively. But, why the gradient vector, compound of these two values gives the direction of maximum increase? Why can't be another vector or direction which gives that? Thank you.

Comment: The directional derivative of $f$ in the direction $v$ at point $p$ is the dot product $\langle \nabla f(p),v\rangle$. By Cauchy--Schwarz this is maximed when...?

Comment: if you don't like Cauchy-Schwarz : check that the gradient is $|C|(1,0)$ when the direction of maximum increase is $(1,0)$. then use the linearity of the gradient with respect to a rotation of the coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directional derivative $D_v = \nabla f_p \cdot v = \|\nabla f_p\| \cos \theta_{\nabla f_p,v}$ and since $-1 \leq \cos t \leq 1$ then the derivative is maximal with value $\|\nabla f_p\|$ i.e in the direction of the gradient.

Comment: To add a few steps between: The maximum value of $D_vf$ at $p$ happens when $\cos\theta = 1$.  This happens when $\theta = 0$, that is, when $\nabla f_p$ and $v$ are pointing in the same direciton.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the directional derivative is maximized when goes in the same direction of the gradient vector. But I can't understand why the gradient itself gives the maximun increase direction, why can't be another vector? Why the gradient have this particularity?

Comment: By definition the directional derivative depends only on the gradient and the directional vector.  There are no other vectors to consider.